# How to access Video from Gallery in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, video, windows-phone-8, gallery

I searched all over net and only found PhotoChooserTask which works only for images. For video I found that there is no way for phone 8 and it comes in 8.1.
Anyway, I found an app

http://www.wpcentral.com/moliplayer-pro-hands

This app is for phone 8 and can play video from any storage. Is there any way and I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

It's true, there's no API for videos to choose.
With Windows Phone 8.1, they provided the API in it.
and it kinda looks like this, BUT this string won't do the whole thing..

```
var userVideoChoose = KnownFolders.VideoLibrary;
```

I don't really know more.

Comment: I also thought that, but there are many apps in store which are providing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need an special permission from MS for accessing KnownFolders in WP8.0. In WP 8.1 that permission is not required.

Comment: What kind of special permission. There is nothing I found on goggle about permissions.

Comment: Contact Microsoft developer relations person in your own country and ask them that you need 'ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO_FULL'. Then you will have permission to access KnownFolders. You can try already adding this capability to your project using emulator.

Comment: There is no such capability. Are you sure you are talking about win phone 8.0

Comment: How do you know there is no such capability? any reference?